# How to compare dates from Excel sheets for value filling purposes on python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel file with 2 sheets.

one sheet containing the data:

```
DATE       TMAX TMIN
20110706    317 211
20110707    322 211
20110708    317 211
20110709    322 211
20110710    328 222
20110711    333 244
20110712    356 250
20110713    356 222
```

and the other sheet includes:

```
Start Date  End Date    Rep Month    Cost    kWh     kW 
7/6/2011    8/3/2011    July     5,065.17    76,640      205 
8/3/2011    9/7/2011    August   5,572.38    86,640      195
```

My goal is to write another column on sheet one (kwh) from sheet two depending on if the date on sheet one falls within the range of a certain kWh.

For An Example:

```
DATE        TMAX    TMIN    kWh
20110706    317   211   76640
20110707    322   211   76640
20110708    317   211   76640
20110709    322   211   76640
20110710    328   222   76640
20110711    333   244   76640
20110712    356   250   76640
20110713    356   222   76640
20110801    344   228   76640
20110802    356   200   76640
20110803    367   200   86640
20110804    361   228   86640
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to do a kind of algorithmic parsing to be able to implement what I am trying to do.

I am already familiar with how to write to a file an read a file/cells with pandas.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter

df = pd.read_excel("thecddhddtest.xlsx",'Sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel("thecddhddtest.xlsx",'Sheet2')
df.head()


df["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DATE"], format="%Y%m%d")
pd.to_datetime(df2["Start Date"], format="%m/%d/%Y")

df3 = df2.set_index("Start Date")


df3["kWh"].reindex(df["DATE"], method="ffill")
df["kWh"] = df3["kWh"].reindex(df["DATE"], method="ffill")
print(df["kWh"])


writer = ExcelWriter('thecddhddtestkWh.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=False)
df2.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2',index=False)
writer.save()
```

which results in:

```
DATE       TMAX TMIN kWh
20110706    317 211
20110707    322 211
20110708    317 211
20110709    322 211
20110710    328 222
20110711    333 244
20110712    356 250
20110713    356 222
```

kWh cell is empty for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's critical to parse the date columns as pandas Timestamps/ numpy datetime64. The best way is to use to_datetime with a format.

```
    In [11]: df
    Out[11]:
        DATE  TMAX  TMIN
0   20110706   317   211
1   20110707   322   211
2   20110708   317   211
3   20110709   322   211
4   20110710   328   222
5   20110711   333   244
6   20110712   356   250
7   20110713   356   222
8   20110801   344   228
9   20110802   356   200
10  20110803   367   200
11  20110804   361   228

In [12]: df["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DATE"], format="%Y%m%d")

In [13]: df
Out[13]:
         DATE  TMAX  TMIN
0  2011-07-06   317   211
1  2011-07-07   322   211
2  2011-07-08   317   211
3  2011-07-09   322   211
4  2011-07-10   328   222
5  2011-07-11   333   244
6  2011-07-12   356   250
7  2011-07-13   356   222
8  2011-08-01   344   228
9  2011-08-02   356   200
10 2011-08-03   367   200
11 2011-08-04   361   228
```

Similarly (with a different format):

```
In [14]: pd.to_datetime(df2["Start Date"], format="%m/%d/%Y")
Out[14]:
0   2011-07-06
1   2011-08-03
Name: Start Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

---

Now, the first observation is that this wouldn't make sense if the periods were not mutually exclusive. This means we only need consider the start date*.

This means you can reindex the seconds sheet, forward fill, and you're done:

```
In [21]: df3 = df2.set_index("Start Date")

In [22]: df3
Out[22]:
            End Date Rep Month      Cost     kWh   kW
Start Date
2011-07-06  8/3/2011      July  5,065.17  76,640  205
2011-08-03  9/7/2011    August  5,572.38  86,640  195
```

This allows you to reindex by the dates from your DataFrame:

```
In [23]: df3["kWh"].reindex(df["DATE"], method="ffill")
Out[23]:
DATE
2011-07-06    76,640
2011-07-07    76,640
2011-07-08    76,640
2011-07-09    76,640
2011-07-10    76,640
2011-07-11    76,640
2011-07-12    76,640
2011-07-13    76,640
2011-08-01    76,640
2011-08-02    76,640
2011-08-03    86,640
2011-08-04    86,640
Name: kWh, dtype: object
```

and set this as the column in df.

```
In [24]: df["kWh"] = df3["kWh"].reindex(df["DATE"], method="ffill")
```

*If there are some "empty" periods we could add in some NaN rows, with the corresponding "empty" start-date.

Comment: Hey Andy, Based of the code you gave me: I tried to print out df["kWh"] value to see if it printed out the right date value according to the date range. But all i get is NaN for all values. What can i do to resolve this?

Comment: @Techno04335 ensure all the date columns are parsed as pandas datetime64/Timestamp columns (rather than strings).

Comment: I have checked that after running the code the files are written at a datetime64/Timestamp for example from sheet 1 : '2011-07-06'  is changed to '2011-07-06 00:00:00'

Comment: I am still having the columns on the kWh being empty

Comment: @Techno04335 my example code is above is actual code which runs. If you put the output of df.to_json into pastebin I'll try and take a look later.

Comment: I have added my code to the question so that you can see my implementation. Thanks.

Comment: @Techno04335 this is hard to diagnose without the actual data, that's why I mentioned to_json. I suspect this is due to dates not being parsed.

Comment: @Techno04335 ah, you need to make sure you do `df2["Start Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["Start Date"], format="%m/%d/%Y")` same as for df1.

Comment: I am still getting 'NaN' utilizing     ' df2["Start Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["Start Date"], format="%m/%d/%Y")'   and df1["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["Start Date"], format="%m/%d/%Y")

Comment: Found the solution, Thanks for you help! [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32923087/how-to-parse-dates-for-comparison-time-range-comparison-for-specific-value/32927204#32927204)